# Privacy in WordPress

Tags: users, private

I am looking to set up a private community using WordPress. The requirements are:

- User can "register" somewhere
- An admin will "approve" them
- The user gets an email "you have been approved"
- The user can then login and access the site and can make posts and reply to stuff

Some plugins are able to help parts of this: `Private`, `Private WP`, `User Roles`, but no combination produces what I want.

Is there a way to do this with WordPress?

Comment: Yes it is possible but you have to write a whole plugin. This can't be achieved by few lines of code. So start extracting what you need from each plugin and combine them.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these features by using the free versions of two plugins,  [Profile Builder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/) that allows you to create a register form, the option of an admin approval and email confimation, login options; and [Members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) that gives you control over which users (by role) have access to post content.